# How do you modify the form after it validates and show's errors

Tags: forms, 6, ajax

I have built a form using CCK in Drupal 6. I have two fields, one which is called health plans and the other is called terms. If I select a health plan I update the terms via AJAX (both are select lists).

So for example: (health_plan_field)Plan A -> (terms_field)(1, 3, 6, 12)

I submit the form and serialize the terms inside a session so that I can keep them.

My problem is that if the form has errors, the terms field is blank because it starts empty until a health plan is selected. So if I have already selected a plan and terms, when the form returns after errors I have nothing.

I have tried to use form_alter (have used this before) by recursively walking down the cck fields on $form to modify the term_field options based on what I have in the session. This does nothing on return.

My code is as follows (called from hook form alter):

```
function acg_pportal_new_service_order_form_cck_walkerTerms(&$array, &$cck_fields) {

$terms = unserialize($_SESSION['termDataFromForm']);
if (!empty($terms)){
    foreach($array as $key => &$value) {
        if (in_array($key, $cck_fields)) {
        unset($value['value']['#options']);
        $first = "";
        foreach($terms as $key2 => $value2){
            if (empty($first)){
                $first = $key2;
            }
            $value['value']['#options'][$key2] = $value2;
        }
            $value['value']['#default_value'] = $first;
            $value['value']['#value'] = $first;
        } 

    }
    }
}
```

Is there anything that you know that will help me in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the form to rebuild on validation fail.

```
$form['#rebuild'] = TRUE;   // cause form rebuild after validation failed
```

Then you can use your `$form_state['values']` inside your `hook_form_alter()`.

OR

You can create a custom function and use the [#after_build](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#after_build) property.

Comment: Just to check, this is where I have placed the line of code you mentioned, in the hook_form_alter.

  $form['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  $form['#after_build'][] = 'acg_pportal_new_service_order_form_after_build';
  $form['#validate'][] = 'acg_pportal_new_service_order_form_custom_validate';
  $form['#submit'][] = 'acg_pportal_new_service_order_form_custom_submit';

Comment: I would do either or, if you just do $form['rebuild'] = TRUE then your hook_form_alter() will get called again instead of serving your form up through cache.  Then you can do some checks in their based on validation errors.  Print out your $form_state['values'] in your hook.  Then view the form and then add some stuff to your inputs and make it fail validation.  See the difference.

Answer (score -1):

`hook_form_alter()` gets called whenever a form is build or *rebuilt*, meaning it'll get called again when the form fails validation. At this point you can look at the `$form_state` variable to see the current state of the form and do whatever you need to do.